# Text of the Mishna Brura (Online English)

Tags: product-recommendation, internet, translation, english, mishnah-berurah

Does anyone know if there is an online translation of the Mishna Brura into English on the internet beginning with the first Siman?

Comment: While this is nowhere near complete, there are several Simanim translated here: http://www.torah.org/advanced/mishna-berura/archives.html It starts with Siman 11, though.

Comment: A partial preview of some volumes can be found on Google Books (e.g. *simanim* [157-201](https://books.google.com/books?id=lIyGmAZUXxgC&printsec=frontcover), [274-307](https://books.google.com/books?id=1kF9RT8oVg0C&printsec=frontcover), [345-372](https://books.google.com/books?id=QfRm-slVgSkC&printsec=frontcover), [373-428](https://books.google.com/books?id=Ji4zpPkvz-0C&printsec=frontcover), [625-651](https://books.google.com/books?id=UidbC9Y3bWQC&printsec=frontcover), and [652-697](https://books.google.com/books?id=P117Lc2t41sC&printsec=frontcover)).

Comment: ... Also [202-241](https://books.google.com/books?id=Ol1eO8VAJcQC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) and [429-452](https://books.google.com/books?id=1VS7gqnWns8C&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: One has to learn MB from the original not from a translation.  Similar to gemoro, no translation can do it justice.  If it is only to know dinim one can use an English kitsur where the translation is as good as the original.

Answer (score 3):

There is a website called [mishnaberurayomi.org](https://mishnaberurayomi.org/) that has archives where you can search for the digest pdfs that has translation (and more) of the mishna berura. Click on the "location in mishna berura" option and enter the siman you are looking for in the search box and then click search.

Comment: consider adding links.

Answer (score 2):

[Sefaria's is incomplete](http://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.1), but it does start with the first chapter as requested.