# Looking for an English translation of the mishna berura

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, mishnah-berurah

Question as stated in title. So far I've only been able to find two through online searching:

- [Ohr Olam](https://ohr-olam.org/mishnah-berurah/), with a very... sparse website. They direct purchasers to [zbermanbooks](https://zbermanbooks.com/seforim-books/halachah/mishnah-berurah), but (1) I can't seem to find a link to the entire set, only hilchos Shabbos, and (2) they don't seem to have even a single page available for preview.
- [Whatever set this is](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000EMKNYC), it's currently unavailable for purchase and the description is nonexistent.

Ideally I'd like to see at least a page or three of preview to see how the translation is laid out/accomplished. Thank you!

Comment: Ohr Olam has not finished yet,they did whole shabbos,some pesach, just finished daled minim.  The black set from feldheim is out of print for a while ,very hard to find full set ,to date they are the only ones who translated the whole MB

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/62215

Comment: As @sam indicated, some volumes of the Feldheim translation by Rabbi Aviel Orenstein (most of them used) are still available for purchase from various sellers (see [here](https://www.biblio.com/search.php?author=aviel+orenstein&pageper=30&order=price_ship_usasc) for example).

Comment: There are some sefarim that aren't easier to understand just because they are translated. M.B. is one of them. It's a rough styleof a rough format.

Comment: [This site](https://mysefer.com/Mishnah-Berurah---English/Hebrew-Edition-Large-size---20-vol.__p-1383.aspx) has a scan of the first few pages of the second set

Answer (score 5):

Ohr Olam is very nice, it is very close to what artscroll would do if they did Mishna Brura. It has translations (of all of Mishna Brura and summaries of Biur Halacha), footnotes, explanations, pictures, introductions, summaries.

It exists in large, small and paperback format. In total they have published the following as of Feb 2024

- 1 volume on Hashkamos Haboker & Tzitzis
- 1 volume of Hilchos Tefillin
- 1 volume of Birchas Hashachar
- 8 volumes of the third Chelek (Hilchos Shabbos)
- All 4 volumes of Hilchos Pesach
- Both volumes of Hilchos Yom Tov
- 1 volume of Rosh Hashana/Yom Kippur
- Both volumes of Hilchos Sukkos & Arba Minim
- 1 volume of Hilchos Chanukah & Megillah

Pictures attached - ask if there is a specific other page you'd rather see.

PS. Can I interest you in a [French translation of MB](http://michnaberoura.com/)? Also very very nice.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: That French edition is beautiful! They are a number of volumes from completion, though (BH they say all will come out in 2020)

Comment: It is - as of March 2024 they have published three volumes, goes slowly but quality remains very high

Answer (score 1):

There is a sample booklet on the website ohr-olam.org when you hit the "our institute" tab.You get an explanation of what the whole Sefer is about. All 8 volumes Of Shabbos & all 4 volumes of Pesach all of Sukkos and Lulav and the first volume of Aleph "Hanhagos Haboker/Tzitzis" are out in stores and online.If I may say so they are doing an unblievable job.