# Shulchan Aruch Hebrew-English Sefer

Tags: product-recommendation, translation, shulchan-aruch

Is there a good Hebrew-English Shulchan Aruch translation for purchase?

I haven’t seen one, which is surprising.

Note: I’m not looking for Kitzur SA

Comment: There's definitely an English print of Mishneh Berurah.

Comment: Consider checking out the Ohr Olam edition, which is probably the one @shmosel is referring to. https://ohr-olam.org/about/

Comment: relevant: [Looking for an English translation of the mishna berura](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/111159/11501)